# Rails 4 – habtm relation with condition on query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have three models:

- Tags (habtm: Posts)
- Posts (habtm: Tags and has many Images)
- Images (belongs to Post)

I want, tag-controller, get all posts in relationship with the tag , that has relations some to images.

Kinda of like:

`Tag.posts.where("images").nil?` (of course not like this, but I hope you see where I’m heading)

First of, I’m really new to Rails, and haven’t done any query conditions on my models (only *.all or *.find)

of course I could fetch all posts belonging to the tag, loop through the posts and remove those that don’t have an image relation, but that doesn’t seem right ;)

**EDIT: 

Perhaps i was unclear, i would like to get all tags (Tags.all()) that has relation with a post, that has relation with an image.

More like: Tags.all.posts.images != null ;) **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking for the existence of a related record is easy in SQL but there's not an "easy" syntax in Rails for it, as far as I know. The trouble with a simple join is that a post having n images will appear in the result set n times -- you can perform a distinct on the result, but that gets increasingly less efficient with increased data sets.

```
Tag.joins(:posts).where("exists (select null from images where images.post_id = posts.id)")
```

Similarly, tags for posts with no image:

```
Tag.joins(:posts).where("not exists (select null from images where images.post_id = posts.id)")
```

Comment: Thank you! This was really close to what i want; Now i get all tags that has posts which has images, but i also get posts that doesnt have images. How should i do to only keep posts with images? Loop? Thank you once again!

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this! I made a pastebin with all code, tables et c. please tell me if you need anything more! http://pastebin.com/35RmzARi

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
Tag.joins(posts: :images)
```

This will load all tags that have posts that have images.